# populate the telerik RadDatePicker with current date in Xaml wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, raddatepicker

how to show the displaydate or selecteddate on load for RadDatePicker with current date

```
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

               <telerik:RadDatePicker x:Name="datepicker1" Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,2" 
                    IsReadOnly="False"
                    AllowDrop="True"
                    SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding  Path=SelectedDate,Mode=OneWay}"
                    />
```

by default the RaddatePicker shows the 1/1/0001, how to show the current date ?

Comment: Try set in your ViewModel "SelectedDate=DateTime.Now"

Comment: I think that we don't, because your variable in VM(SelectedDate) is the SelectedValue and it's set to 1/1/0001, so this value is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this and it works fine with me and i had simple DatePicker

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datepicker1" Grid.Column="1"   
                Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,2"                       
                AllowDrop="True"                
                SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"  
                />
```

I hope this will help