# Set DisplayDateStart on DatePicker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

Is there a way I can set the DisplayDateStart property on a DatePicker (Telerik) control in XAML without having a property in my ViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of setting the property in the XAML directly, you could do the following:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datepicker1" Grid.Column="1"   
                Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,2"                       
                AllowDrop="True"                
                SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"  
                />
```

Reference: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485249/populate-the-telerik-raddatepicker-with-current-date-in-xaml-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker DisplayDateStart="1/1/2010" DisplayDateEnd="11/15/2010"/>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddatetimepicker/features/date-items

Comment: @user1278533 Well, that was not one of your specifications in the original question and this is just an example, but you can always do what Quinn did.